# Multiple modals in bootstrap4 not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, web, bootstrap-4

I have 2 modals that are triggered by selection of a drop down menu. If I have the "multi-part-delete modal" first and the "multi-part-move" modal second then the "multi-part-move" one does not show. The screen goes dark but the modal does not appear.

If I swap them around then the move one works and the delete one doesn't show. Anyone know how I can get them both to work.

```
    <!-- Multi-Part Delete Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="multipartdeletemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Delete Selected Parts?</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <i data-icon="ei-trash" data-size="l" class="trash"></i>
        <h5>Are you sure you want to delete these parts?<br>
            This process cannot be undone</h5>
        <form action="{% url 'multi-delete' project.id %}" method="post" id="multidelete">{% csrf_token %}</form>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button form="multidelete" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <!-- Multi-Part Move Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="multimovemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Move Selected Parts?</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <i data-icon="ei-trash" data-size="l" class="trash"></i>
        <h5>Please select group?</h5>
        <form action="{% url 'multi-delete' project.id %}" method="post" id="multimove">{% csrf_token %}</form>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button form="multimove" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like both modal-body divs are missing closing tags, before the footer?

Comment: Stacking modals can be a hassle. 90% of the time it has to do with one of the modals not having the correct z-index. Open the second modal, and in devtools, locate the added div at the end of your document. That's where you'll be able to track down exactly what's happening to the second modal.

Comment: Thanks Phil. It was the missing closing tags!

Answer (score 3):

use this IIFE function and you will have mulitple stackable modal support on bootstrap 4

```
(function multiple_modal() {
    $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        var zIndex = 1040 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
        $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
        }, 0);
    });

    $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        $('.modal:visible').length && $(document.body).addClass('modal-open');
    });
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, stacked modals are currently not working in Bootstrap 4.1. What I did was make them sequentially close/open each other. For example, when a child("stacked") modal opens from a parent modal, the parent modal closes, and when a child modal closes, it re-opens a parent(previously opened) modal - so there's always one modal open at a time.

On the child modal, I have a data attribute `data-parent-modal="#parentExampleModal"`

I have the Javascript as below:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    let $this = $(this),
        $parentModal = $this.parent().find($this.data('parent-modal') + '.modal');
    if ($parentModal.length) {
        $parentModal.modal('hide');
        $this.on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $parentModal.modal('show');
        });
    }
});
```

If you need further explanation, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with CSS by selecting the second modal

```
.modal:nth-of-type(even) {z-index: 1052 !important;}

.modal-backdrop.show:nth-of-type(even) {z-index: 1051 !important;}
```